# How to make the div load closed without requiring two clicks to open

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

1.I Apologise if this is a silly question. How would I make it so
the div remains closed and only requires one click to open
(currently two). So ideally it would load closed and the when the
button is clicked once it would open the div with a list meu in```

```js
`<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mobilemenu");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    margin: 0 !important;
  }
  h2 {
    line-height: 1.4em!important;
  }
  nav {
  }
  nav a {
    display: none!important;
  }
  #mobilemenu {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  }
  button.devicesnav {
    display: flex!important;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="devicesnav" onclick="myFunction()">Menu</button>

<div class="hero">
   <div id="mobilemenu">
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
      <li>Fout</li>
   <li>Five</li>
</div>
`
```

Comment: please post your HTML and JavaSCript

Comment: sorry i thought i had one sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "***toggle class"*** to open and close element block.please have a look over toggle class for solution

[Click here to know about Toggle Class](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

You can even use Collapse component in bootstrap to get solution for your problem
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

Comment: Not a very well detailed answer. Where's the example? What exactly is *"toggle class"*? Take a few minutes to read [answer]

Comment: I have the toggle working but the contents of the div are visible before it's toggled. When i press the button (toggle) the div appears. How do i make the div contents appear/disappear at the same time and not visible to start with? I want a UL in there (Menu).